# Refresh JFrame with ActionListener

Tags: java, swing

This has been asked many times already, but i really cant solve this problem.
I'm trying to refresh a table in a JFRame while it is running after i added a row so I dont have to restart it.I've tried the following method, but it still doesnt work. 
The method is used in a ActionListener.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JButton;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class GUI2 extends JFrame {

    private static JPanel contentPane;
    private static JTable table;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            GUI2 frame = new GUI2();

    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public GUI2() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        setContentPane(contentPane);

        table = new JTable();
        contentPane.add(table, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JButton btnRefresh = new JButton("Refresh");
        contentPane.add(btnRefresh, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        btnRefresh.addActionListener(new Refresh());
    }
    public class Refresh implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            repaintGUI();
        }
    }
    public static void repaintGUI() {

            contentPane.repaint();
            contentPane.validate();
            table.repaint();
            table.validate();
    }
}
```

Something similar to that. The Button is pressed after i have changed something in the table.

Comment: For better help, please better define your problem. What do you mean by "refresh a JFrame", since that is a very vague statement, one difficult to understand? Also, please consider creating and posting an [sscce](http://sscce.org) or [mcve] where you condense your code into the smallest bit that still compiles and runs, has no outside dependencies (such as need to link to a database or images), has no extra code that's not relevant to your problem, but still demonstrates your problem.

Comment: Also note that you appear to be mis-using the validate and repaint methods. These methods are likely not needed for what you are trying to do. Again, if you can show us more pertinent code (see the links above), we'll likely be able to better help you. Please check out the [help] and the [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections to see how to improve this question.

Comment: Thanks for posting code, but when running the code, no JTable is displayed. I've changed the contentPane's layout to BorderLayout, and now a blank JTable appears. I've also overridden contentPane's paintComponent method, to verify that calling `repaint()` makes it repaint, and in fact it does. But your posted code shows no issue that is not working. Please improve it.

Comment: [For example -- this shows that repaint is doing its job](http://pastebin.com/aTZyunyq). But again, you will need to improve your code to help us better understand your problem. And again I will bet you that you do not want to call repaint nor revalidate. What you likely need to do is to update the displayed JTable's model, something you're not showing in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your posted code doesn't work well as an example since the JTable is not visualized, but if you give the contentPane a BorderLayout, the JTable displays, and if refresh is pushed, then the GUI does in fact repaint, but as expected, it doesn't change its appearance since a simple repaint or revalidate won't change appearances if nothing else is done.

OK, here's where I need to guess since your question is still lacking key details (in the future, please ask it with an eye towards our point of view: people who have no idea what your current program does, looks like or what your problem is), but if the problem is that you're trying to reset a JTable's data, then the solution is to do just that -- reset your JTable's model by calling `setRowCount(0)` which will remove all data from the JTable, if it uses a DefaultTableModel. If it doesn't use the DefaultTableModel, then make sure to either give the JTable a new table model, or else call a method of your own table model that removes all data.

For instance:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class GUI3 extends JPanel {
   private static final String[] COLS = { "Foo", "Bar", "Baz" };
   private static final int ROWS = 5;
   private DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(COLS, ROWS);
   private JTable table = new JTable(tableModel);
   private ResetAction resetAction = new ResetAction("Reset", KeyEvent.VK_R);
   private RandomizeAction randomizeAxn = new RandomizeAction("Randomize",
         KeyEvent.VK_Z);

   public GUI3() {
      JPanel btnPanel = new JPanel();
      btnPanel.add(new JButton(resetAction));
      btnPanel.add(new JButton(randomizeAxn));

      setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      add(new JScrollPane(table));
      add(btnPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
   }

   private class ResetAction extends AbstractAction {
      public ResetAction(String name, int mnemonic) {
         super(name);
         putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);
      }

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         tableModel.setRowCount(0);
      }
   }

   private class RandomizeAction extends AbstractAction {
      private Random random = new Random();

      public RandomizeAction(String name, int mnemonic) {
         super(name);
         putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);
      }

      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         tableModel.setRowCount(ROWS);
         int rows = ROWS;
         int columns = tableModel.getColumnCount();
         for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < columns; col++) {
               int data = random.nextInt(10);
               tableModel.setValueAt(data, row, col);
            }
         }
      };
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      GUI3 mainPanel = new GUI3();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("GUI3");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes, i wanted kind of a reset. I' m not using Defaul Table Model. I solved the problem now by changing the Action Listener. It disposes the program now and then restarts it. Does the trick too. Thank you for the help

Comment: @Rob: sorry, but I don't like that solution as it smells of throwing out the baby with the bath water, and I still feel that a much stronger solution is close at hand if you could only improve the question. Please consider doing this. Also, please consider at least up-voting the answer for the effort involved in creating it.

Comment: I upvoted your answer. I dont want to do a reset, i want a update of the DefaultTableModel. I think i might have found a way to update my DefaultTableModel by using 

model.fireTableDataChanged();

But now im getting Null-Pointer-Exception Errors. I really have to look over my code again..